# How do I switch cameras for scanning QR code from Website - Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, camera

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime running Lollipop and need to scan a qr code through Chrome. The website allows for me to press the QR code scan option but when I do, the front facing (selfie) camera turns on and it's impossible for me to turn the phone around and be able to line it up with the QR code without being able to see what I'm doing. When I turn on the camera alone, it's correctly using the rear camera, yet it insists on using the selfie camera through the website.

There does not appear to be any option to change the camera on the website itself (www.blockchain.info).

How do I change this to use the rear camera to scan the QR code?

Comment: Download UC Browser/Uc Mini. They have built in options for QR code scanning.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend you use a separate barcode scanner to scan QR codes. That would solve your issues.

[Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en)